# Update with Join query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, oracle10g

what is wrong in query? (it executes indefinitely)

```
UPDATE table1 t1 SET (t1.col,t1.Output) = (
  SELECT t2.col, t3.Output + t2.col
  FROM tabl2 t3 
  LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t3.Join_Key = t2.Join_Key
  WHERE t2.col is not NULL);
```

Please, help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "executes indefinitely"? It does not complete, does not parse, updated inconsistent rows or what?

Comment: Also, could you please explain in plain English what did you mean to achieve? Your subquery as it is now is not correlated and the update will fail if it returns more than one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query does not make a whole lot of sense with the generic table1, table2, and join_key references.

If this is not what you are looking for, it would be helpful to have some sample data to get a better idea of what results you are looking for.

```
update table1 t1
   set t1.col = (select t2.col
                 from table2 t2
                 where  t1.join_key = t2.join_key(+)  
                  and  t1.col is not null),
       t1.output = (select t2.output + t1.col
                    from  table2 t2
                   where  t1.join_key = t2.join_key(+)  
                     and  t1.col is not null);
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless your `SELECT` subquery returns a single row, your `UPDATE` statement should fail with the error

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Generally, whey you have a correlated update, you need some condition that relates rows in the outer table `T1` to rows in the inner subquery in order to ensure that the subquery returns a single row.  That would generally look something like

```
UPDATE table1 t1 SET (t1.col,t1.Output) = (
  SELECT t2.col, t3.Output + t2.col
  FROM tabl2 t3 
  LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t3.Join_Key = t2.Join_Key
  WHERE t2.col is not NULL
    AND t1.some_key = t2.some_key);
```

Finally, this `UPDATE` statement is updating every row in `T1`.  Is that what you intend?  Or do you only want to update the rows where, for example, you find a match in your subquery?

Comment: Yes, I need to find a match in subquery

Comment: is that your update statement updated all records in table1. Because UPDATE table1 without WHERE clause